# Get module from CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

Tags: winapi, assembly, module, masm

I can fill out a list box with processe names, for this I use PROCESSENTRY32 struct. But when I try to get th32ParentProcessID from PROCESSENTRY32 struct, I get an error, eax equal -1.

My structures:

```
    PROCESSENTRY32 STRUC
    dwSize              DWORD ?
    cntUsage            DWORD ?
    th32ProcessID       DWORD ?
    th32DefaultHeapID   DWORD ?
    th32ModuleID        DWORD ?
    cntThreads          DWORD ?
    th32ParentProcessID DWORD ?
    pcPriClassBase      DWORD ?
    dwFlags             DWORD ?
    szExeFile           dw MAX_PATH dup(?)
    PROCESSENTRY32 ENDS
```

```
    MODULEENTRY32 STRUCT
    dwSize          DWORD ?
    th32ModuleID    DWORD ?
    th32ProcessID   DWORD ?
    GlblcntUsage    DWORD ?
    ProccntUsage    DWORD ?
    modBaseAddr     DWORD ?
    modBaseSize     DWORD ?
    hModule         DWORD ?
    szModule        db MAX_MODULE_NAME32+1 dup(?)
    szExePath       db MAX_PATH dup(?)
    MODULEENTRY32 ENDS
```

My function:

```
        ;Modul begin
        push PROCDATA.th32ProcessID
        push TH32CS_SNAPMODULE
        call CreateToolhelp32Snapshot@8
        mov mhSnapshot, eax
        ;EAX = -1 Why?        
        mov MODULDATA.dwSize, sizeof MODULEENTRY32
        push offset MODULDATA
        push mhSnapshot
        call Module32FirstW@8
        ;Module end
```

I have the correct structures?

Comment: What about error checking?

Comment: I used a GetLastError, and I've got this: ERROR_BAD_LENGTH 24 (0x18) The program issued a command but the command length is incorre

Comment: @lostsky25 read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot): "*TH32CS_SNAPMODULE Includes all modules of the process specified in th32ProcessID in the snapshot. To enumerate the modules, see Module32First(). **If the function fails with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH, retry the function until it succeeds**... **If the function fails, it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. To get extended error information, call GetLastError()**. Possible error codes include ERROR_BAD_LENGTH.*" `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is `(DWORD)-1`.